# xenserver - add secondary hard drive

Tags: xen, xenserver

I had a secondary hard drive installed on my xen server but it's not showing up in xencenter.

Does anyone know the command to do this? I'd also appreciate the command to add a secondary drive inside a xen container.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have more information? Which Xen Version? Which operating system? Is the hdd shown in the root xen system?

Comment: afaik, Xenserver doesn't have the capability to add a new SR on a local disk from the XenCenter GUI. This site may help: http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX121313

Answer (score 2):

Here are instructions on how to add additional disk drives to XenServer. Works with 5.5 and 5.6.

http://www.schirmacher.de/display/INFO/How+to+add+additional+disks+to+XenServer+host

Comment: I was just looking how to do that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also create local storage as ext3.  This has the benefit of providing "thin provisioning" with the drawback is that you can't expand this storage easily.  If you choose to use 100% of this disk, I would personally go with ext3:

http://www.scriptkiddie.org/blog/2010/06/20/xenserver-5-6-thin-provisioning-with-ext3/